# Apache mod_rewrite not resolving as expected

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, apache2

I am attempting to implement a simple Apache mod rewrite and am having an issue with it. The pattern I am providing does not seem to be matching,although from what I can tell it should.

I am placing these rules in my .htaccess file. Here is the file in it's entirety:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^détails-details-eng.php/([\d]+)/*([\w'-]*)$ détails-details-eng.php?id=$1 [L]
# done for testing
RewriteRule ^mytest/?$ index.php [NC,L]
```

The functionality I am looking for is, coincidentally similar to how stackoverflow's urls look. When I browse to

```
détails-details-eng.php/1/somtext
```

I go the détails-details-eng.php page but the id of 1 is not being passed(a quick print_r($_GET) confirms). I know mod_rewrite is enabled because going to :

```
mytest
```

resolves to index.php as it should.

Could anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here? When I check my regular expression via [RegExr](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/)
it seems to be what I am looking for. Any help is very much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `^détails-details-eng.php/([\d]+)(/[\w/'-]+)?$`?

Comment: @ Chris - Thanks for the response. I tried your suggestion but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the rule that you will need:

```
RewriteRule ^détails-details-eng\.php/([^/]+)/[^/]*/?$ détails-details-eng.php?id=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried your suggestion of escaping the . but the rule is still not working, any other suggestions?

Comment: When you open this URI `/détails-details-eng.php/1/somtext` what do you get in your browswer? And does `détails-details-eng.php` really exist in DOCUMENT_ROOT for yu?

Comment: Bah, I just realized my issue was the encoding being used by my text editor. I changed it to UTF-8 without BOM and it worked as expected. Thanks.